# How do I move the DOM elements down when I insert a new one so they don't overlap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a javascript function that inserts a span on clicking a button.  But the problem is when I insert it, it overlaps the other elements. How can I move the other elements down when the button is clicked to make room for the inserted element? And then move them back up when the element is removed?  Here is my code:

```
 $(".top-button").on("click", function() {
  if (this.nextElementSibling) {
    $(this.nextElementSibling).slideToggle(600);
  };
 });

$(".bottom-button").on("click", function() {
  $(this.nextElementSibling).slideToggle(600);
});
```

And a working demo here http://codepen.io/andrewcockerham/pen/xjgkL/

Basically, when I click on the yellow and green 'buttons' on Entry 1, the MP and IP boxes toggle, but they overlap the other elements (When Entry 1 is collapsed, {click on it}).  How can I make the other elements move out to make room when the MP and IP appear, then return to their normal place when the MP or IP disappear?

I've tried `appendChild()`, `insertAfter()`, `insertBefore()`, all without success.

Please forgive the ugly demo and ugly code - its a WIP! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it is a matter of absolute positioned elements vs. dynamic height - try wraping all those elements in a absolute positioned element and position the child elements relative

Comment: I tried that but currently all of the parent elements, such as ".entry" are `position: relative;` and if I switch them to `absolute` then all of the positioning doesn't line up correctly.  Maybe I'm using `position` `relative` and `absolute` wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it, so I'll answer my own question.

Basically I just inserted a blank or empty div 'behind' the inserted span, thus moving the DOM down or up.  Here's the JS code:

```
$(".top-button").on("click", function() {
  if (this.nextElementSibling) {
    if ($(this.nextElementSibling).css('display') == "none") {
      // insert blank element to move the DOM down
      $("<div class='top-blank'><span></span></div>").insertBefore($(this).parent());
    } else {
      // remove blank element when collapse dropdown
      $(this).parent().siblings('.top-blank').slideUp(600);
    }
    $(this.nextElementSibling).slideToggle(600);
  };
});

$(".bottom-button").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this.nextElementSibling).css('display') == "none") {
    $("<div class='blank'><span></span></div>").insertAfter($(this).parent());
  } else {
    // remove inserted stuff
    $('.blank').slideUp(500);
  }
  $(this.nextElementSibling).slideToggle(600);
});
```

and the CSS:

```
.blank {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  left: -50px;
}
.top-blank {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
```

updated Codepen working example: http://codepen.io/andrewcockerham/pen/xjgkL/

Not sure if this is the best or most proper way, but it works in my case.  Interested to hear if there are other better solutions for this.